# External Table is Azure Synpase Returning empty dataset

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Good Morning,

I attempted to create an external table using data from my Azure Gen 2 datalake. However, I encountered an error when attempting to run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Uksponsor.Sponsors
```

Below, I have posted the code that I wrote to create a database, credential, external data source, external file format, and external table. Although my code runs, it returns an empty dataset without any data.

```
CREATE DATABASE LicensedSponsors
 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8;
GO

USE LicensedSponsors;
GO

/* Create a password for credential */
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'tales'; 

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL Manageid
WITH
    IDENTITY='Managed Identity'; 
GO

/* CREATE EXTERNAL DATASOURCE */
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE sponsor_Data 
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'abfss://ffs@datagen2db.dfs.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = Manageid
);
GO

/* CREATE AN EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT */
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT CsvFormat
    WITH (
        FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
        FORMAT_OPTIONS (
            FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
            STRING_DELIMITER = '"'
        )
    );
GO

/* CREATE A SCHEMA */
CREATE SCHEMA Uksponsor;

/* CREATE AN EXTERNAL TABLE */
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Uksponsor.Sponsors -- Specifying schema
    (
    Organization VARCHAR(100),
    City VARCHAR(100),
    County VARCHAR(100),
    SponsorshipType VARCHAR(100),
    VisaRoute VARCHAR(100)
    )
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'Register of licensedsponsors/**',
    DATA_SOURCE = sponsor_Data ,
    FILE_FORMAT = CsvFormat
);
GO
```

Below i have posted the image of what was returned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfNsY.png)

I have tried to search online and look at other forums, such as this one: [External table Azure Synapse does't returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699664/external-table-azure-synapse-doest-returning-data), but I haven't had any luck. I also attempted to change the data types when creating the external table, but I am still encountering the same problem. I even tried to create it automatically by using the "create external table" option, but it still returns an empty dataset. I suspect that there may be something wrong with the file or my code that is causing the issue.

Comment: can you add sample data from file on which you are creating external table?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers
It is an 8.51 CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> External Table is Azure Synpase Returning empty dataset

The issue is the size of datatype it might exceeding beyond the limit what you given `varchar(1000)` try with `varchar(max)`

**sample code:-**

```sql
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE [Uksponsor].[tablename] (
[Organisation Name] varchar(MAX),
[Town/City] varchar(MAX),
[County] varchar(MAX),
[Type & Rating] varchar(MAX),
[Route] varchar(MAX)
)
WITH (
LOCATION = 'Register of licensedsponsors/**',
DATA_SOURCE = [datasource],
FILE_FORMAT = [fileformat]
)
GO
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I did actually try varcharmax before, but it didn't work. My thinking may be the MAX statement is case-sensitive.

Comment: Glad this solution worked for you.